# How should I execute script block parameters in a PowerShell function?

Tags: powershell

If I create a PowerShell function with a parameter of type `[scriptblock]`, **which** method is the best to execute the script block inside the function? And **why**?

I am aware of the following options:

- `.` source operator
- `&` (call) operator
- `Invoke-Expression`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` runs the scriptblock in the *current* scope. `&` runs the scriptblock in a *child* scope (same as running the scripblock via its `Invoke()` method). Which one you want to use depends on the outcome you want to achieve.

**Demonstration:**

Running via `Invoke()` method:

```
PS C:\> $s = { $a = 2; $a }
PS C:\> $a = 1
PS C:\> $s.Invoke()
2
PS C:\> $a
1
```

Running via call operator:

```
PS C:\> $s = { $a = 2; $a }
PS C:\> $a = 1
PS C:\> & $s
2
PS C:\> $a
1
```

Running via dot-sourcing operator:

```
PS C:\> $s = { $a = 2; $a }
PS C:\> $a = 1
PS C:\> . $s
2
PS C:\> $a
2
```

If you need the scriptblock to modify something in the current scope: use the `.` operator. Otherwise use call operator or `Invoke()` method.

[Do not use `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Comment: I like the Invoke() method. I was unaware of that one. I think it make the code more readable. I think for my functions this will work in most cases. The scoping rules are subtle. I would have missed that and learned the hard way!

Comment: The script blocks I am running will need to share a few variables between them. So if I use the & (call) operator is there a recommended way to make these variables visible to multiple script blocks? Is $global: script the way to go in this case? I'm a little concerned about the . (source) operator because the script block code will share the same variables as the caller's scope which might lead to very tricky bugs.

Comment: @MatthewMacFarland If you want all the variables shared between scriptblocks it would be simpler to just use the `.` operator. If you want some variables shared between scriptblocks but not all of them you could use the `global:` or `script:` scope modifier. With that said, I wouldn't recommend actually doing this as it reeks of bad design.

Comment: @AngsarWiechers Interesting. So I definitely want to share only a couple of variables between the code in the various scripts blocks but I certainly don't want bad design either. Kinda stuck. Do you know of any references or blogs on a good design for this sort of situation?

Comment: Joking aside, no, I don't know of a good reference short of software engineering studies. What I can tell you is that scriptblocks are PowerShell's implementation of anonymous functions. Anonymous functions are very useful in some situations, but I think for what you seem to try to do classic functions with proper parametrization would be a better approach. You want a clear data flow through your code. Data flow via global variables is a mess and a pain to debug.